# Make call OnItem click in android using columnIndex

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursor

Any one help me i did nt get idea to solve this issue. Actually i get contact list in listview with its name and number in my application. When i click a list number from list it directly calls only last number in list. Example: i have numbers : as abc, bca, cab in order it directly class cab OnClick pressed. but actually i should call exact number what i (Click) pressed. Suggest me to clear this process please.

```
public class newsapi extends Activity {

    ArrayList<SelectUser> selectUsers;
    List<SelectUser> temp;
    ArrayList<String> phonesn;
    // Contact List
    ListView listView;
    // Cursor to load contacts list
    Cursor phones, email;
    String phoneNumber;
    // Pop up
    ContentResolver resolver;
    SearchView search;
    SelectUserAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.feedlayout);

        selectUsers = new ArrayList<SelectUser>();
        resolver = this.getContentResolver();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);

        phones = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        LoadContact loadContact = new LoadContact();
        loadContact.execute();

        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        // *** setOnQueryTextListener ***
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Load data on background
    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            // Get Contact list from Phone

            if (phones != null) {
                Log.e("count", "" + phones.getCount());
                if (phones.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(newsapi.this,
                            "No contacts in your contact list.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    Bitmap bit_thumb = null;
                    String id = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
                    String name = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    String EmailAddr = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA2));
                    String image_thumb = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI));
                    try {
                        if (image_thumb != null) {
                            bit_thumb = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                    resolver, Uri.parse(image_thumb));
                        } else {
                            Log.e("No Image Thumb", "--------------");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SelectUser selectUser = new SelectUser();
                    selectUser.setThumb(bit_thumb);
                    selectUser.setName(name);
                    selectUser.setPhone(phoneNumber);
                    selectUser.setEmail(id);
                    selectUser.setCheckedBox(false);
                    selectUsers.add(selectUser);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Cursor close 1", "----------------");
            }
            // phones.close();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUsers, newsapi.this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Select item on listclick
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                        int i, long l) {
                    Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                            + Uri.encode(phoneNumber.trim())));
                    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });

            listView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        phones.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use CursorAdapter and Loaders although its not directly related to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `phoneNumber` variable is getting replaced in the loop ending in the last result.

You need to get it from your data list.

add this line to your `onPostExecute` method

```
phoneNumber = selectUsers.get(i).getPhone();
```

Like this

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                        int i, long l) {
                    Log.e("search", "here---------------- listener");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    phoneNumber = selectUsers.get(i).getPhone();
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                            + Uri.encode(phoneNumber.trim())));
                    callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: i m creating a button from (textview layout) of phonenumber of listview. Is that possible to OnClick of button make a call. if yes give me idea pls.  Actually i dont need listview On click. just need listview's textview Onclick

Comment: @UserAndroid I didn't get it. Can you clarify? (Perhaps put as another question)

Comment: Actually i dont need listview Onclicklistener.and that listview have name, phonenumber and other , when phonenumber onclick it calls.  :) give me idea or suggestion pls

Comment: You can add a click listener in for the button in the `getView` method of your CustomAdapter

Comment: Thanks @Boss i got exact result from ur suggestion